# How to create audio-video service using Avahi on RPi?

Tags: raspbian, audio, streaming-video, streaming

I have a RPi board Model B Version 1.2 running with Raspbian OS.

I want to communicate with Apple devices. As I studied about it and have found that it uses Bonjour, which is an implementation of Zeroconf protocol. Also, similarly Avahi is a Zeroconf implementation for Linux.

I have downloaded necessary packages related to Avahi.

For audio and video, there are "raop" and "airplay" services respectively.
So, I created these services on RPi in the "/etc/avahi/services" directory with name "airplay.service".

Here is the file "airplay.service".

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?><!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">

<service-group>
        <name replace-wildcards="yes">service on %h</name>

        <service>
                <type>_airplay._tcp</type>
                <port>47000</port>
                <txt-record>model=AppleTV3,2,1</txt-record>
                <txt-record>deviceid=48:5d:60:7c:ee:22</txt-record>
                <txt-record>features=0x100009FF</txt-record>
                <txt-record>srcvers=160.10</txt-record>
                <txt-record>rmodel=PC1,1</txt-record>
        </service>

        <service>
                <type>_raop._tcp</type>
                <port>5002</port>
                <txt-record>txtvers=1</txt-record>
                <txt-record>ch=2</txt-record>
                <txt-record>cn=0,1,2,3</txt-record>
                <txt-record>et=0,1</txt-record>
                <txt-record>sm=false</txt-record>
                <txt-record>pw=false</txt-record>
                <txt-record>sv=false</txt-record>
                <txt-record>sr=44100</txt-record>
                <txt-record>ss=16</txt-record>
                <txt-record>tp=UPD</txt-record>
                <txt-record>vn=3</txt-record>
                <txt-record>md=0,1,2</txt-record>
                <txt-record>ek=1</txt-record>
                <txt-record>am=AppleTV2,1</txt-record>
        </service>
</service-group>
```

The "/etc/default/avahi-daemon" file,

```
AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0
```

and the "/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf" file

```
# This file is part of avahi.
#
# avahi is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
# published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the
# License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# avahi is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
# ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY
# or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public
# License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
# License along with avahi; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307
# USA.

# See avahi-daemon.conf(5) for more information on this configuration
# file!

[server]
#host-name=foo
#domain-name=local
#browse-domains=0pointer.de, zeroconf.org
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
allow-interfaces=eth0,wlan0
#deny-interfaces=eth1
#check-response-ttl=no
#use-iff-running=no
#enable-dbus=yes
disallow-other-stacks=yes
#allow-point-to-point=no
#cache-entries-max=4096
#clients-max=4096
#objects-per-client-max=1024
#entries-per-entry-group-max=32
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

[wide-area]
enable-wide-area=yes

[publish]
#disable-publishing=no
#disable-user-service-publishing=no
#add-service-cookie=no
publish-addresses=yes
publish-hinfo=yes
publish-workstation=no
publish-domain=no
#publish-dns-servers=192.168.50.1, 192.168.50.2
#publish-resolv-conf-dns-servers=yes
#publish-aaaa-on-ipv4=yes
#publish-a-on-ipv6=no

[reflector]
#enable-reflector=no
#reflect-ipv=no

[rlimits]
#rlimit-as=
rlimit-core=0
rlimit-data=4194304
rlimit-fsize=0
rlimit-nofile=768
rlimit-stack=4194304
rlimit-nproc=3
```

These services can discover by "Avahi Zeroconf Browser" utility on RPi, it shows service on raspberrypi.

**But, can't discover by iPad.**

Are those txt-record parameters correct and in right place?
I tried with different ports e.g. 7000 in '_airplay._tcp' and 5000 in '_raop._tcp'.

What should changes have to made to make it discover on iPad?

If anyone has idea about it then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what to make of this rant. `avahi` is enabled by default on latest Raspbian (you don't tell us which version). If you wish to use `afp` protocol to communicate with Apple devices install `netatalk`. Search this Forum for `netatalk` for more background.

Comment: you might need a little bit more than just avahi to get airplay to work with your iPad. Search for either 'shairport', 'rplay' or even kodi.

Comment: @Milliways: Its "Linux raspberrypi 4.4.19-v7+". I want to use "raop" and "airplay" services, which are for audio and video. Actually I want to do mirroring of Audio and Video from iPad to my RPi. Will check for mentioned things.
Thanks

Comment: @Gotschi: Means, Would Avahi services alone not be able to do this tasks? like this. Yes, I tried with 'shairport'. But, there are 2 issues 1. Its ready-made, we can't configure it. and 2. Its only for audio. I need for video too. 'rPlay' I used too. But after upgrading iPad's os to 9.0.3 its not working. And for 'Kodi', I am new for this. Will look for this. But, Is it possible to mirror audio-video from iPad to RPi?
Thanks for info.

Comment: Apple breaks ^H^H^H^H^H changes the secret Airplay Mirroring protocol on regularly and on purpose. Did i mention that they keep it secret ?